# Sending parameter to java method from jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, jsp

FacadeGUIcontroller : class that imported in jsp.

this code doesn't accept variable as its parameter

```
function runmlp()
{

 FacadeGUIcontroller.printk(document.getElementById( 'txtneuron').value);
}
```

But this code is working correctly.

```
 FacadeGUIcontroller.printk("myname");
```

Answer (score 3):

`FacadeGUIcontroller.printk(document.getElementById( 'txtneuron').value);`

You are trying to code javascript stuff in jsp and assumed to be executed at server which is wrong.

JavaScript gets executed at client's browser , where java code from jsp gets executed at server

---

**See**

- [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)
- [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: That is correct, JS is only for client side and JSP handles these sort of things on the server side. +1

Comment: I write these codes in Scriptlet.What must be done?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: We want to call a method of class FacadeGUIcontroller that accept one string arqument.we put these codes in <%%> tag.It works properly when i use a direct string in " " mark.my problem is:my code doesn't accept a variable as parameter..

Comment: Please look at `DWR` carefully